# Populate 2 or more tables in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a way to populate more than 1 table in MVC, because the method only allows me to return One ModelView or I don't know how to return more. Do I have to build the table in the controller and store into a ViewData and display the viewData in the page?

Edit: Sorry, I think I didn't express the idea. The point is that I want to populate 2 or more datatables in the page.

For example, if I have a Customer and that Customer has 5 Contacts and 5 Addresses, I want to display the Customer Information and 2 Tables with Contacts and Addresses.

```
for each p in modelview
{
"<td>" + p.Name + "</td>"
}


for each p2 in modelview2
{
"<td>" + p2.Product + "</td>"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return more than one model, but it will require a compound model for the view and the use of prefixes when binding the controller parameter.

Say you have a View Model that is:

```
public class VM
{
   public FooClass Foo { get; set; }
   public BarClass Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller, you would have

```
public ActionResult MyAction( [Bind(Prefix="Foo")]FooClass foo,
                             [Bind(Prefix="Bar")]BarClass bar )
{
   ...
}
```

And in your view you would use:

```
<%= Html.TextBox( "Foo.Value" ) %>
<%= Html.TextBox( "Bar.Name" ) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

ViewData is a dictionary; you can store multiple items in there, simply via:

```
ViewData["foo"] -= ...
ViewData["bar"] -= ...
```

You can then get these (separately) in the view. The other approach is to declare a type that *encapsulates* both properties, and use an instance of that type as the model (and a typed view). Personally, I prefer the simple key/cast approach.

Comment: For simply getting data to the view (list/show), I would agree. This approach isn't always the simplest when getting data from the view (new/update), though.  Especially, if you already have a compound model, say User with related Contacts.

Comment: foor and bar value will be the html code for a binded datatable?

Comment: No; they are whatever data you put in them; the *view* creates html, not the controller